# java input reader failing to recognize particular values of file

Tags: java

This is my code for reading in a line and understanding the inputs, viz everything before the tab character, and the label, i.e. after the tab:

```
    // READ INPUT
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../PA-A-train.dat"));

    while (reader.readLine() != null) 
    {
        String[] label_detector = reader.readLine().split("\t");
        String trueLabel = label_detector[label_detector.length - 1];



        String inputs = label_detector[label_detector.length - 2];
        System.out.println("these are inputs: " + inputs);


        System.out.println("this is the corresponding label: " + trueLabel);
    }
    reader.close();
```

And this is my file:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 A    0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 B    0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 C    0 0
 0 0 0 1 1  0 0
 0 0 1 0 0  0 0
 0 0 1 0 1  0 0
 0 0 1 1 0  0 0
 0 0 1 1 1  1 0
 0 1 0 0 0  0 0
 0 1 0 0 1  0 1
 0 1 0 1 0  0 0
 0 1 0 1 1  1 1
 0 1 1 0 0  0 0
 0 1 1 0 1  1 1
 0 1 1 1 0  1 0
 0 1 1 1 1  1 1
 1 0 0 0 0  0 0
 1 0 0 0 1  0 0
 1 0 0 1 0  0 0
 1 0 0 1 1  1 0
 1 0 1 0 0  0 0
 1 0 1 0 1  1 0
 1 0 1 1 0  1 0
 1 0 1 1 1  1 0
 1 1 0 0 0  0 0
 1 1 0 0 1  1 1
 1 1 0 1 0  1 0
 1 1 0 1 1  1 1
 1 1 1 0 0  1 0
 1 1 1 0 1  1 1
 1 1 1 1 0  1 0
 1 1 1 1 1  1 1
```

But my output looks like this:

```
these are inputs:  0 0 0 0 1 B 
this is the corresponding label: 0 0
these are inputs:  0 0 0 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 0 0
these are inputs:  0 0 1 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 0 0
these are inputs:  0 0 1 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 0
these are inputs:  0 1 0 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 0 1
these are inputs:  0 1 0 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
these are inputs:  0 1 1 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
these are inputs:  0 1 1 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
these are inputs:  1 0 0 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 0 0
these are inputs:  1 0 0 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 0
these are inputs:  1 0 1 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 0
these are inputs:  1 0 1 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 0
these are inputs:  1 1 0 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
these are inputs:  1 1 0 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
these are inputs:  1 1 1 0 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
these are inputs:  1 1 1 1 1 
this is the corresponding label: 1 1
```

as you can see, the first line is completely ignored, it also ignores the 3rd line. Why is that?

**PROPOSED SOLUTION LOOKS LIKE THIS:*

```
        String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        String[] label_detector = line.split("\t");

        String trueLabel = label_detector[label_detector.length - 1];


        String inputs = label_detector[label_detector.length - 2];
        System.out.println("these are inputs: " + inputs);


        System.out.println("this is the corresponding label: " + trueLabel);
    }
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `readLine()` twice per iteration. Once in

```
while (reader.readLine() != null)
```

and once in

```
String[] label_detector = reader.readLine().split("\t");
```

Change the code to

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] label_detector = line.split("\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only those 2 lines, but about half of your lines are missing. The problem is at `reader.readLine()`. You read 2 lines, but only process 1 line.

You can fix it like this.

```
// READ INPUT
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../PA-A-train.dat"));

String line;//new variable

while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) //read the line and compare
{
    String[] label_detector = line.split("\t");//split
    String trueLabel = label_detector[label_detector.length - 1];



    String inputs = label_detector[label_detector.length - 2];
    System.out.println("these are inputs: " + inputs);


    System.out.println("this is the corresponding label: " + trueLabel);
}
reader.close();
```